# Order of cycles in graph

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

In a school assignment, I am to use contradiction to prove that if a graph is bipartite then all of its cycles have even order. In this context, what does it mean for a cycle to have even order? I tried using google and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29), but I am no closer to understanding what it means. Could you please explain it?

Comment: In this context, the *order* of a cycle is the number of edges in it.

Comment: @Servaes I understand now, thank you.

Comment: The order of the graph refers to the number of vertices. A cycle graph happens to have as many vertices as edges. The number of edges in the graph is referred to as its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $G$ contains only cycles of odd order. Then $G$ is not bipartite since the $V(G)$ cannot be partitioned into two partite sets, $U$ and $W$ such that the edges of $G$ join a vertex of $U$ to a vertex of $W$. Consider the $5$-cycle $C_5$ and this will be more clear.